# how to set hostname via DHCP in Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, dhcp, netplan, systemd-networkd

I'm new to the systemd world (and Ubuntu in general), but I tried to dig as deep as I could to try to answer this question myself, but not really getting anywhere.

I'm setting up VMs for both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, and trying to have the hostname automatically set via DHCP. I can't seem to get it to work.

I guess one issue is that I'm not sure my DHCPd (Infoblox) is actually sending the hostname field in the DHCPv4 request. This is due to the fact that if I check on the `/run/systemd/netif/leases/*` file, there is no `HOST*` field. The netplan documentation seems to suggest that if the lease includes `HOSTNAME`, then by default the hostname should be set (`use-hostname` is `true` by default). I've also tried removing the `/etc/hostname` file which didn't do anything.

Has anyone successfully gotten their bionic or focal Ubuntu server's hostname set via DHCP? Anything special that needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

Disable cloud-init service:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Delete file /etc/hostname:

```
sudo rm /etc/hostname
```

Remove line with 127.0.1.1 in the file /etc/hosts

Reboot

Comment: Could you elaborate further on the diabling of the cloud-init -- would this be post-install?

Comment: I'm running 20.04, and these steps did not work.